# Custom domain in gh-pages throwing 404 error failed to load resource

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

A github repo is set with gh-pages which is working with github provided link
username.github.io/projectname
where we were able to see the project running perfectly
When we added a custom domain **[www.projectname.com](http://www.projectname.com)** getting below error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACKAm.png)

for this do we need to change index.html for custom domain. If yes how come it worked before custom domain.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I guess we need to change "PUBLIC_URL" in Index.html but I didn't tried as I'm not sure.